# android :How to set cursor to next field if prvious field is auto filled?

Tags: android, cursor

I have two input field username and password.I am using the Shared Preferences for storing the username and use that value for auto fill on relaunching the app.
I want it to set cursor on password field if there is stored value in username filed.
but in my case cursor is always in username filed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fill in your username field with your stored data, call `requestFocus()` on your password field. e.g. `password.requestFocus()`.

Answer (score 1):

**[requestFocus()](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html)**

Any element representing a View object can include this empty element, which gives its parent initial focus on the screen .

For your requirement , You should call

```
  password_et_obj.requestFocus();
```